# Regex to determine string after marker

Tags: regex, string, parsing

I am using the following regex to determine the next word found after a certain marker:

```
(?<=marker:\W{1})(\w+)
```

How can this be updated to determine the next 8 characters after the marker, including space, or other special chars like `-` or `/`

Thanks,
Alex

Source looks like this:

```
test : 1205
no.: abc    
marker: 12345678
something: xxx
```

and I require `12345678`

Comment: Are you looking for the next 8 characters after the word 'marker' or after a specific symbol? It's not very clear from the question

Comment: does not seem to work ... testing using http://regexlib.com

Comment: are those special chars or space interchangeable? Are them maximum one or can be repeated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.` instead of `\w` in your capturing group and use another quantifier:

```
(?<=marker:\W)(.{8})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.` to match 'any character';

`(?<=marker:\W{1})(.{8})`